# Getting GGally:ggparcoord to work

Tags: r, ggally

```
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
diamonds.samp <- diamonds[sample(1:dim(diamonds)[1],100),]
gpd <- ggparcoord(data = diamonds.samp,columns = c(1,5:10),groupColumn = 2)
```

throws the error

```
> Error: (list) Object can not be converted to 'double'
```

This is from the examples from GGally. Is this (another) bug?

Comment: Works for me (ggplot2 `2.0.0` and GGally `1.0.0`).

Comment: @Pascal: Same version here.

Comment: I cannot get your error. Try to run this code in a clean session of R.

Comment: @Pascal: That worked. Sorry for the fuss - though I don't quite get what that was all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run again from a clean session.